# Is it a bad idea to store my 6 months expirations sessions in database?

Tags: php, database, performance, session

I've around 500,000 unique visitors, and I want my visitors be able to use my website a bit like StackOverflow. I mean you don't need to register but you have kind of an account which stores some preferences.

To do that, I create a member in the same I'll do for a user which wants to register, however I set some dummy values like user1234 as username, and a guest role.

I want them to be able to use it as long as they want without registering but not infinite which is no sense to me, so I'd like to purge every 6 months for example.

However It may be a bit heavy if I plan to a lot of trafic.

Someone told me that I could work with memcached in front of MySQL; is it a good idea? 
How would you implement such thing?

By the way it means that I'll have the same amount of member in my member database which can grow too much, then I'll need to purge this too.

What do you think?

Comment: 500,000 uniques per day?  Month?  Year?

Comment: @harkre, I know about that it's why I choosed to store them in database, but the idea would have been to use mysql behing memcached to avoid the load but not sure about that however.

Comment: @Brad, no for six monthes, but as we're going to go US market it may be per monthes : )

Comment: No-one knows your site. Nobody can tell you what will be fitting. You will need to find out yourself.

Comment: Well it is a bit similar as SO does, if you come you don't need to register to ask question, as soon as you ask a question, a user is created with a an associated cookie which expires in one year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're expecting *every single one* of those anonymous visitors to lurk around your site without registering for six months? I highly doubt even a fraction of a percent of the lurkers would care to do that.

I'd just keep it simple and store that data in a `$_SESSION` variable. If the anonymous users want to keep their preferences, then they should register. You don't need to tax your website's performance just to accommodate lazy users...

Comment: Well, we checked the stats and well we want to incitate user to register, we saw that a lot of them continues to come to our website without registering, they can keep their votes and some favorites, so yeah, every single visitor is an anonymous member we should take care of.

Comment: By the way I'm actually using $_SESSION, I just changed the session handler to use a database.

Comment: @Trent: Maybe the reason those users aren't registering is because you aren't giving them much of a reason to do it. It's up to you to implement what you think would work, so I'm just making a suggestion.

Comment: I totally agree with you on that, however there is a time when even an attractive website will have non registered users, for those I still need to keep them in session, that's how that works. So if my website haven't much traffic it wouldn't be a problem but the traffic is getting bigger and bigger

Comment: Well, all I can do is suggest :P

Answer (score 2):

What about saving a cookie on the client side which will store the preferences of the user ?

Comment: Well seeing as a cookie is easily changeable by just about anyone else along with your website, that's not a very good alternative to keep personal or secure information. However, if you don't mind security or privacy (settings or preferences that could be made public), then by all means go ahead, just make sure you validate a lot!!

Comment: Hi, the idea behind that is that I can work with my guest in the same way I'll do with other users, all my method apply to a User whatever he is a guest, a member or an admin, by the way, it is collaborative website where votes are stored, we don't much care if a vote is casted twice if the user cleans his session.